# Non-editable input fields

Tags: visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce

How to make an input field non-editable when it has values. ie. to make an input field non-editable after it has dynamically fetched values from an object field. I am having my code within my visualforce page and have used html and javascript for this functionality.

My code
      `Related Object: <input  style="display:inline;" name="baseObject" id="baseObject" value="{!dTemplateObj.RelatedObject__c}" />`

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Have you tried `html-readonly = True` or `disabled = True` ?

Comment: If the input field is blank it should fetch values from the corresponding object filed and after that when someone opens the visualforce page[in preview mode] to edit the existing content the field should become non-editable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button add onclick method

```
<input  style="display:inline;" name="baseObject" id="baseObject" value="{!dTemplateObj.RelatedObject__c}" onclick="disable()"/>

function disable()
    {

    if( document.getElementById('baseObject').value != '' )
    {
    document.getElementById("baseObject").disabled = true;
    }

    }
```

The above code will disable the input field when it has contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "disabled" attribute in input tag.

```
<input  style="display:inline;" name="baseObject" id="baseObject" value="{!dTemplateObj.RelatedObject__c}" disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: giving disbled="true" makes the field non-editable totally. I don't want that, the field should be editable when it is blank and should be non-editable when it has contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any thought about using `action support` for this? You could associate an `action support` with the input field and during an `onchange` event , a function can be called which checks whether `dTemplateObj.RelatedObject__c` is not null, if not null it will set a `boolean variable` to `true`. The boolean value should be specified in `disabled` attribute of the input field tag.